# SVG animation low performance on safari

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, canvas, svg-animate

I am working on svg animation with changing path and my biggest problem is safari, it is really smooth on other browsers but safari is just terrible with it

```html
<svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="1215"
      height="719"
      viewBox="0 0 1215 719"
      fill="none"
      overflow="visible"
    >
      <g filter="url(#filter0_bi_5278_11355)">
        <path fill="black" fill-opacity="0.3">
          <animate
            attributeName="d"
            dur="15s"
            repeatCount="indefinite"
            values="
            M444.67 20.1608C721 62.5 845.564 130.758 848.496 211C802.5 375.484 683.447 373.131 317.503 443.725C-48.4406 514.319 -40.3365 386.351 60.996 343.5C161.498 301 222.997 190.5 48.4993 106C-120.501 31.0001 188.996 -34 444.67 20.1608Z;
            M533.673 100.16C827 286.5 822.85 299 827 340.5C837 440.5 784.944 397.906 419 468.5C53.0563 539.094 133.457 430.241 216 357.5C296 287 201.996 128.5 27.4981 43.9996C-102.004 -14.5005 265.5 -30.5 533.673 100.16Z;
            M444.67 20.1608C721 62.5 845.564 130.758 848.496 211C802.5 375.484 683.447 373.131 317.503 443.725C-48.4406 514.319 -40.3365 386.351 60.996 343.5C161.498 301 222.997 190.5 48.4993 106C-120.501 31.0001 188.996 -34 444.67 20.1608Z"
          />
        </path>
      </g>
      <defs>
        <filter
          id="filter0_bi_5278_11355"
          x="-33.6094"
          y="-33.176"
          width="1282.4"
          height="785.486"
          filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
          color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
        >
          <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix" />
          <feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImageFix" stdDeviation="17" />
          <feComposite
            in2="SourceAlpha"
            operator="in"
            result="effect1_backgroundBlur_5278_11355"
          />
          <feBlend
            mode="normal"
            in="SourceGraphic"
            in2="effect1_backgroundBlur_5278_11355"
            result="shape"
          />
          <feColorMatrix
            in="SourceAlpha"
            type="matrix"
            values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"
            result="hardAlpha"
          />
          <feOffset dy="4" />
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="41.5" />
          <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1" />
          <feColorMatrix
            type="matrix"
            values="0 0 0 0 0.890196 0 0 0 0 0.0313726 0 0 0 0 0.478431 0 0 0 1 0"
          />
          <feBlend
            mode="normal"
            in2="shape"
            result="effect2_innerShadow_5278_11355"
          />
        </filter>
      </defs>
    </svg>
```

I have tried some research how to made it on canvas or with some library, but i haven't even touched these things and I think this is too much for me with my actual knowledge. I haven't found any solution for my problem on stack overflow also

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit sceptical whether your performance problem is caused by Safari, or by the hardware it is running on. If it is a mobile device with iOS, reduced processing power might also be a reason. So, without further evidence, let's look at optimizing your filter definition.

- Half of the filter does nothing but waste processing time. Everything up to `<feBlend result="shape" />` can be deleted. Use the `SourceGraphic` as input instead, and there will be no difference in the result.
- Take care to restrict the filter effect region to the minimum required. The smaller the needed image buffers, the faster they can be computed. `x="-5" y="-5" width="860" height="710"` is enough.

```html
<svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="1215"
      height="719"
      viewBox="0 0 1215 719"
      fill="none"
      overflow="visible"
    >
      <g filter="url(#filter0_bi_5278_11355)">
        <path fill="black" fill-opacity="0.3">
          <animate
            attributeName="d"
            dur="15s"
            repeatCount="indefinite"
            values="
            M444.67 20.1608C721 62.5 845.564 130.758 848.496 211C802.5 375.484 683.447 373.131 317.503 443.725C-48.4406 514.319 -40.3365 386.351 60.996 343.5C161.498 301 222.997 190.5 48.4993 106C-120.501 31.0001 188.996 -34 444.67 20.1608Z;
            M533.673 100.16C827 286.5 822.85 299 827 340.5C837 440.5 784.944 397.906 419 468.5C53.0563 539.094 133.457 430.241 216 357.5C296 287 201.996 128.5 27.4981 43.9996C-102.004 -14.5005 265.5 -30.5 533.673 100.16Z;
            M444.67 20.1608C721 62.5 845.564 130.758 848.496 211C802.5 375.484 683.447 373.131 317.503 443.725C-48.4406 514.319 -40.3365 386.351 60.996 343.5C161.498 301 222.997 190.5 48.4993 106C-120.501 31.0001 188.996 -34 444.67 20.1608Z"
          />
        </path>
      </g>
      <defs>
        <filter
          id="filter0_bi_5278_11355"
          x="-5"
          y="-5"
          width="860"
          height="710"
          filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
          color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
        >
          <feColorMatrix
            in="SourceAlpha"
            type="matrix"
            values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"
            result="hardAlpha"
          />
          <feOffset dy="4"  />
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="41.5" />
          <feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1" />
          <feColorMatrix
            type="matrix"
            values="0 0 0 0 0.890196 0 0 0 0 0.0313726 0 0 0 0 0.478431 0 0 0 1 0"
          />
          <feBlend
            mode="normal"
            in2="SourceGraphic"
            result="effect2_innerShadow_5278_11355"
          />
        </filter>
      </defs>
    </svg>
```

- The resulting animated shape is partially transparent. That means an extra computation step is needed for blending it with its background. Is that really needed? If the background of the shape is monochromatic, you can start with a `<path>` with `fill-opacity="1"` and a `fill` that is already the mix of the colors (for a white background for example, `#b2b2b2`). The first `feColorMatrix` can then be deleted completely.
  The values of the second `feColorMatrix` might need a bit of tweaking, but visually, I cannot make out any difference.

```html
<svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="1215"
      height="719"
      viewBox="0 0 1215 719"
      fill="none"
      overflow="visible"
    >
      <g filter="url(#filter0_bi_5278_11355)">
        <path fill="#b2b2b2">
          <animate
            attributeName="d"
            dur="15s"
            repeatCount="indefinite"
            values="
            M444.67 20.1608C721 62.5 845.564 130.758 848.496 211C802.5 375.484 683.447 373.131 317.503 443.725C-48.4406 514.319 -40.3365 386.351 60.996 343.5C161.498 301 222.997 190.5 48.4993 106C-120.501 31.0001 188.996 -34 444.67 20.1608Z;
            M533.673 100.16C827 286.5 822.85 299 827 340.5C837 440.5 784.944 397.906 419 468.5C53.0563 539.094 133.457 430.241 216 357.5C296 287 201.996 128.5 27.4981 43.9996C-102.004 -14.5005 265.5 -30.5 533.673 100.16Z;
            M444.67 20.1608C721 62.5 845.564 130.758 848.496 211C802.5 375.484 683.447 373.131 317.503 443.725C-48.4406 514.319 -40.3365 386.351 60.996 343.5C161.498 301 222.997 190.5 48.4993 106C-120.501 31.0001 188.996 -34 444.67 20.1608Z"
          />
        </path>
      </g>
      <defs>
        <filter
          id="filter0_bi_5278_11355"
          x="-5"
          y="-5"
          width="860"
          height="710"
          filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
          color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
        >
          <feOffset dy="4"  />
          <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="41.5" />
          <feComposite in2="SourceGraphic" operator="arithmetic" k2="-1" k3="1" />
          <feColorMatrix
            type="matrix"
            values="0 0 0 0 0.890196 0 0 0 0 0.0313726 0 0 0 0 0.478431 0 0 0 1 0"
          />
          <feBlend
            mode="normal"
            in2="SourceGraphic"
            result="effect2_innerShadow_5278_11355"
          />
        </filter>
      </defs>
    </svg>
```

Comment: I checked it on few laptops and even with your changes Safari can't handle it smoothly, when other browsers are handling it very well. I just shared fragment of my animation, there are two more "blobs" similar to this and if I change it like u said, it still is laggy. I think it might be because path is too complex, but it has to be like this :/

Comment: I would be very suprised if the paths are a factor, they are actually very simple. (The rendered length of a path has more influence on performance than its number of vertices.) If there are multiple "blobs", are they also animated independently of each other? Do they overlap? Partially transparent regions moving in relation to each other are the heaviest performance factor I have encountered so far. Try as hard as you can to make the filter effect regions not intersect, or at least make sure there is no partial transparency in overlaping regions.